# Constructing a string array with Frida

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, frida

I'm trying to call a function with Frida that takes a string array as one of its arguments.

```java
public void coolFunction(long value, String[] strArr);
```

Within Java it gets called like this:

```java
long importantValue = 4L;
String[] importantArr = new String[]{"TEST"};
coolFunction(importantValue, importantArr);
```

The overload looks like this: `.overload('long', '[Ljava.lang.String;')`

I *could* probably create a string array from scratch, but I don't know how to express it in Javascript. What's the Frida equivalent of `new String[]{"TEST"}`?

Because of that I tried to turn an `ArrayList<String>` into a `String[]`, which also wasn't successful.

As far as I can tell there are two simple ways to turn `ArrayList<String>` into `String[]`:

Attempt #1:

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("TEST");
String[] stringArray = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

If I try to express it with Javascript it looks like this:

```js
var AL_class = Java.use("java.util.ArrayList");
var arrList = AL_class.$new();
arrList.add("TEST");
var stringArray = arrList.toArray(Java.use("[Ljava.lang.String;").$new(0));
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
Error: no supported overloads
```

Attempt #2:

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("TEST");
Object[] objectArray = list.toArray();
String[] stringArray = (String[]) objectArray;
```

Javascript:

```js
var AL_class = Java.use("java.util.ArrayList");
var arrList = AL_class.$new();
arrList.add("TEST");
var arrayButAsObject = arrList.toArray();
var stringArray = Java.cast(arrayButAsObject, "[Ljava.lang.String;");
```

This fails because it assumes that I want to use Javascript's `toArray()` function.

The solution to this problem is probably very simple but I've been stuck here for quite a while now and can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Another trick when calling a function is not to let Frida chose the correct overload but instead define the overloaded function to be called (`targetMethod = `) and then `targetMethod.call` it as shown in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65969575/150978

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to construct a `java.util.List` and then convert it to an array I would use the Frida function [Java.array](https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#java-array) and directly construct a Java String array:

```
var javaStringArray = Java.array('java.lang.String', [ "Test" ]);
```